# How to make Full screen vertical scroll view with List view in that

Tags: android, listview

[image: My screen image]

i want to make this page in vertical scroll view mode but there is one list view which you can see below,i have listview items which are coming from web service

**Main Problem:**

My screen is scrolling but listview item are not scrollable I can only find first result from web service

I used fill_parent property in xml still listview item is showing in small window.
Anyone please tell me how to create this type of screen I have search this on net but did't get any correct idea..thank you

here is my Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_back_ground" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <include
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/header_mf" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cg_report_btn" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/header_yellow_line" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:src="@drawable/header_yellow_line" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/backkground_img_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Violin Genius takes the highschool championships"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/gallery_assignment_name"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgViewGalleryBackgroundPic"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/u15_normal"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_feed"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgViewDetailTumbNail"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/u17_normal_small" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Vote  ."
                                android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="Comment  ."
                                android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="Share"
                                android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_person_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                android:text="@string/gallery_person_name"
                                android:textSize="8dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_views"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="0"
                                android:textSize="8dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                android:layout_width="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/view_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_comment"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                android:textSize="8dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                android:layout_width="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/comment_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_favorite"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="8dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                android:layout_width="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/heart_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_distance"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="8dp" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                android:layout_width="10dp"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/pin" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider_line" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:fillViewport="true" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/gallery_image_detail"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="@string/gallery_assignment_detail"
                        android:textSize="8dp" >
                    </TextView>
                </ScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapViewGallery"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:apiKey="0X_Jyk3FLOVfS4dJSGin89ME-m3u3QBwVFkXpvQ"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:enabled="true" >
                </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--                     <ListView -->
<!--                         android:id="@+id/listViewGalleryDetail" -->
<!--                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
<!--                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!--                         android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" -->
<!--                         android:padding="5dp" > -->
<!--                     </ListView> -->
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hope u have not put list view in scrollbar. as it is not advisable.

You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView. 
Check this link:-  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: yea i removed my list view from there and now i want to add my list item directly to that linear layout so what should i do because list view have its own scroll view so we have to maintain both thing

Comment: First of all you should your list view out of scroll bar, and then simply add list view to the root layout, and then u cn proceed as u proceed for simple list view. (This is generic solution).

Comment: Thank you,But from this way can i able to make the whole page scrollable i want to make this full screen should be scroll vertically with list view item.do you have any example links for reference.

Comment: See your whole page will be scrollable with two portion. first will be your entire page without list view, and other will be list view. So this way your screen will be divided into two parts. and these two will be separately scrollable.
Somthing like this

<LinearLayout xmlns...>
  <ScrollView>
      //your elements here
   </Scrollview>
   <ListView/>
</LinearLayout>

This way you will acheive what you want, just u need to divide the two part carefully, that is how much weight u should put to each part

Comment: yes your way is helpful for me but i have one more idea is it possible that if i give ld to that linear layout where were my list view was before at bottom and then i directly add listview item run time on that linear layout (with use of addView)can i try that?

Comment: See you can add list item programatically while declaring the list view in corresponding activity class. in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have resolved my issue with use of **listview.addHeaderView(view);** with use of this property i have added my second view on top of my list view and its working like charm.

one thing that we have to make sure that,we must call this method before calling setAdapter() of our listview.

Comment: Just an insight, be carefull with the AddHeader method performed on object that inherits from BaseAdapter, don't forget to remove the added instances when the activity exits. Otherwise your activity will be leaking memory since a new header/footer will be added for each call. Also when you call this function, your adapter will be wrapped around a WrapperListAdapter if it does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View) You might need to clear the data in the adapter too.

Comment: Hey Tnx for the sharing more info on this, That will be very help full.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/main_back_ground" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <include
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            layout="@layout/header_mf" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cg_report_btn" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/header_yellow_line" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            android:src="@drawable/header_yellow_line" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/backkground_img_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Violin Genius takes the highschool championships"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                android:textSize="12dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/gallery_assignment_name"
                                android:textSize="10dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgViewGalleryBackgroundPic"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/u15_normal"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:background="@drawable/app_feed"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imgViewDetailTumbNail"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/u17_normal_small" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                        android:text="Vote  ."
                                        android:textSize="12dp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:text="Comment  ."
                                        android:textSize="12dp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:text="Share"
                                        android:textSize="12dp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_person_name"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                        android:text="@string/gallery_person_name"
                                        android:textSize="8dp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_views"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:text="0"
                                        android:textSize="8dp" />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/view_icon" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_comment"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                        android:textSize="8dp" />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/comment_icon" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_favorite"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:textSize="8dp" />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/heart_icon" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_distance"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:textSize="8dp" />

                                    <ImageButton
                                        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:background="@drawable/pin" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/divider_line" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ScrollView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="70dp"
                            android:fillViewport="true" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/gallery_image_detail"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="false"
                                android:text="@string/gallery_assignment_detail"
                                android:textSize="8dp" >
                            </TextView>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                            android:id="@+id/mapViewGallery"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="70dp"
                            android:apiKey="0X_Jyk3FLOVfS4dJSGin89ME-m3u3QBwVFkXpvQ"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:enabled="true" >
                        </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewGalleryDetail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:padding="5dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this

Comment: i tried this xml but now my list view is not showing on screen full page is scrolling but list view is gone

Comment: in mine division is shown. in any case try match_parent with scroll view

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll both of the scroll view using this trick .
It worked for me .

Suppose you have two scroll view L1 is inside L2 then use this code in JAVA.

```
L1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                L2.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

With this you can scroll both of the scroll view

Comment: hey i am not using two scroll view but i have one scroll view for whole page and second one is list view so it have own scrolling property so have to add list view in full scrollable screen

Comment: yes i know .. write code on listview s touch listner .. you can scroll outer scroll view and listview both ..

Comment: only one condition is that if you want to scroll main scroll view you have to touch out side of list view.